# Como colocar PHP dentro de um echo?

Tags: php, echo

Como faço para ao invés disso:

```php
elseif ( $qtd == 1000 ) {
    echo $this->__('<b>produto customizável</b><br><span class="product-name">ENTRE EM CONTATO</span><div style="backgroud:#333">');    
}
```

Fazer com que funcione isso:

```php
elseif ( $qtd == 1000 ) {
    echo $this->__('<a class="askproduct popup" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('askfordetails/askfordetails', array('product_id' => $_product->getId())) ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('askfordetails')->__('ENTRE EM CONTATO') ?></a>');  
}
```

Alguém sabe se isso é possível?

Comment: Isso que postei é o trecho de uma condicional, que caso o estoque de determinado produto seja igual a 1.000 é para mostrar no front um link composto pela url base + /askfordetails/askfordetails/index/product_id/ + o id do produto

Comment: veja todo o trecho de código:
<?php
       $qtd = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
       if ( $qtd == 0 ) {
       echo $this->__('<span class="product-name">PRODUTO<br>ESGOTADO</b>');}
       elseif ( $qtd == 1000 ) {
        echo $this->__('<b>produto customizável</b><br><span class="product-name">ENTRE EM CONTATO</span><div style="backgroud:#333">'); 
       } else {
       ?>
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
       <?php } ?>

Comment: Pra que você fica abrindo e fechando o PHP em vez de usar só um `<?php` lá em cima e um `?>` embaixo?

Comment: Sou bem leigo em PHP, não sei o motivo de estar assim. Só sei que já revirei a internet atrás de uma solução para isso e não encontro, já li bastanta sobre concatenar o php dentro do echo, mas não consegui executar!! sabe como isso deveria ficar?

Comment: Tá tão cheio de problema que fica difícil até começar a responder. Olha, reescrevi seu código de uma maneira mais normal, mas não arrumei erros de implementação, que dependem do resto do seu sistema: **http://pastebin.com/mnPF8Dgw** - Seria legal você pegar ao menos uma noção básica do que está fazendo, senão mesmo com respostas boas, você vai ter problema para aplicar ao seu caso prático.

Comment: Obrigado, Bacco. Sei disso!

Comment: Em resumo, vc pode dar varios "echo" em linhas separadas sem precisar concatenar. `echo '1';` `echo '2';` `echo '3';` mesmo em linhas separadas vai sair 123 na tela. Ou se preferir, pode usar o ponto: `echo Funcao1() . Funcao2()` faz a concatenação. Outro exemplo: `echo 'x'.(2+2).'y';` vai mostrar `x4y` na tela.

Comment: Isso eu entendi, mas continuo não conseguindo exibir isso:<a class="askproduct popup" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('askfordetails/askfordetails', array('product_id' => $_product->getId())) ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('askfordetails')->__('ENTRE EM CONTATO') ?></a>
    no lugar disso: <b>produto customizável</b><br><span class="product-name">ENTRE EM CONTATO</span><div style="background:#333">

Comment: Edite a pergunta clicando no [edit] logo abaixo dela, coloque todos os detalhes que precisar, e aprenda a formatar suas perguntas aqui: **http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help** - Leia também **[ask]** para conseguir melhorar sua postagem, assim aumenta a chance de conseguirmos ajudar.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z4davmkh

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, mas de qq forma, muito obrigado Bacco! Vou estudar um pouco sobre concatenar e quebrar mais a cabeça. valeu mesmo

Answer (score 13):

Basta utilizar a concatenação. Se você quer exibir conteúdo dinâmico dentro do echo, utilize a concatenação. No seu caso ficaria:

```
elseif ( $qtd == 1000 ) {
    echo $this->__('<a class="askproduct popup" href="'.Mage::getUrl("askfordetails/askfordetails", array("product_id" => $_product->getId())).'">'.Mage::helper("askfordetails")->__("ENTRE EM CONTATO").'</a>');  
}
```

O que foi utilizado aí é simples de entender, ao invés de fazer:

```
echo '<a href="<?php echo $variavel?>">Clique aqui</a>';
```

Fazemos assim:

```
echo '<a href="'.$variavel.'">Clique aqui</a>';
```

Comment: Mais uma caso que a resposta salva a pergunta +1